# strip white space and count lines/steps

Tags: python, list, append

I am reading an xyz file and trying to append all the steps to a list. When I strip the white space, and separate the columns, the numeric value of each step is truncated, and now, incorrect. I am using the folllowing code:

```
filename = open('test.xyz','r')
lines = filename.readlines()
lines = [line.replace(' ', '') for line in lines]
steps=[]

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("i="):
        steps.append(line[2])

       
print(steps)    


filename.close()
```

and the out put is ['0', '5', '1']

the steps should be 0, 50, 100. The number of steps in this file becomes very large ( 1M Steps), and I cant seem to find a way to retain the correct step number.

[here is a pic of the file that is being read for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MwDK.png)

Comment: Do `steps.append(int(line.split("=")[1]))`

Comment: I get the following error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-3962855ff79b> in <module>
      8 for line in lines:
      9     if line.startswith("i="):
---> 10         steps.append(int(line.split("=")[1]))
     11 
     12 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0,time'

Comment: Ah, okay. Don't post pictures of text. Paste it into a code formatted block on the question. The main issue is you have to pull out multiple characters of the string and not just one. Start with providing a small sample of lines from the text, and try to make sure this has all the different combinations of formats you might expect. From this set of lines, also show the desired output in terms of python objects.